# Not all code paths return a value in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
public int Queue()
    {
        using (Entities server = new Entities())
        {
            var ServerId1 = (from serverID in server.AppPM_Patches
                             where serverID.PatchStatus == "NotStarted" && serverID.ServerId == 1
                             select serverID.ServerId).Count();
            var ServerId2 = (from serverID in server.AppPM_Patches
                             where serverID.PatchStatus == "NotStarted" && serverID.ServerId == 2
                             select serverID.ServerId).Count();
            var ServerId3 = (from serverID in server.AppPM_Patches
                             where serverID.PatchStatus == "NotStarted" && serverID.ServerId == 3
                             select serverID.ServerId).Count();
            if (ServerId1 == 0 && ServerId2 == 0 && ServerId3 == 0)
            {
                return ServerId1;//Convert.ToInt32(ServerId1);

            }
            else if (ServerId1 == 1 && ServerId2 == 0 && ServerId3 == 0)
            {
                return ServerId2;
            }
            else if (ServerId1 == 1 && ServerId2 == 1 && ServerId3 == 0)
            {
                return ServerId3;
            }
            else if (ServerId1 > ServerId2 && ServerId1 > ServerId3)
            {
                if (ServerId2 > ServerId3)
                {
                    return ServerId3;
                }
                else
                {
                    return ServerId2;
                }
            }
            else if (ServerId2 > ServerId3 && ServerId2 > ServerId1)
            {
                if (ServerId1 > ServerId3)
                {
                    return ServerId3;
                }
                else
                {
                    return ServerId1;
                }
            }
            else if (ServerId3 > ServerId1 && ServerId3 > ServerId2)
            {
                if (ServerId1 > ServerId2)
                {
                    return ServerId2;
                }
                else
                {
                    return ServerId1;
                }
            }
            else if (ServerId1 == ServerId2 && ServerId2 == ServerId3 && ServerId1 == ServerId3)
            {
                return ServerId1;
            }
            else if (ServerId1 == ServerId2 && ServerId1 > ServerId3 && ServerId2 > ServerId3)
            {
                return ServerId3;
            }
            else if (ServerId2 == ServerId3 && ServerId2 > ServerId1 && ServerId3 > ServerId1)
            {
                return ServerId1;
            }
            else if (ServerId1 == ServerId3 && ServerId1 > ServerId2 && ServerId1 > ServerId3)
            {
                return ServerId1;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting the error(not all code paths return a value) in the method. This method returns an int value as i have defined. But don't know why this error happens even if i have returned an int value. Could any one help me out?

Comment: I would try to code the equivalent of this SQL:  `... GROUP BY ServerID ORDER BY COUNT(x), ServerID` and take the first record because what you have will be awful when you add ServerID = 4, 5, ... n.

Comment: +1 to counter down vote. Nothing wrong with asking a genuine question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public int Queue()
        {

                using (Entities server = new Entities())
                {
int retVal=0;//initialize it your value
                    var ServerId1 = (from serverID in server.AppPM_Patches
                                     where serverID.PatchStatus == "NotStarted" && serverID.ServerId == 1
                                     select serverID.ServerId).Count();
                    var ServerId2 = (from serverID in server.AppPM_Patches
                                     where serverID.PatchStatus == "NotStarted" && serverID.ServerId == 2
                                     select serverID.ServerId).Count();
                    var ServerId3 = (from serverID in server.AppPM_Patches
                                     where serverID.PatchStatus == "NotStarted" && serverID.ServerId == 3
                                     select serverID.ServerId).Count();
                    if (ServerId1 == 0 && ServerId2 == 0 && ServerId3 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal=ServerId1;//Convert.ToInt32(ServerId1);

                    }
                    else if (ServerId1 == 1 && ServerId2 == 0 && ServerId3 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal=ServerId2;
                    }
                    else if (ServerId1 == 1 && ServerId2 == 1 && ServerId3 == 0)
                    {
                        retVal=ServerId3;
                    }
                    else if (ServerId1 > ServerId2 && ServerId1 > ServerId3)
                    {
                        if (ServerId2 > ServerId3)
                        {
                            retVal= ServerId3;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            retVal=ServerId2;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (ServerId2 > ServerId3 && ServerId2 > ServerId1)
                    {
                        if (ServerId1 > ServerId3)
                        {
                            retVal=ServerId3;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            retVal=ServerId1;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (ServerId3 > ServerId1 && ServerId3 > ServerId2)
                    {
                        if (ServerId1 > ServerId2)
                        {
                            retVal=ServerId2;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            retVal=ServerId1;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (ServerId1 == ServerId2 && ServerId2 == ServerId3 && ServerId1 == ServerId3)
                    {
                        retVal=ServerId1;
                    }
                    else if (ServerId1 == ServerId2 && ServerId1 > ServerId3 && ServerId2 > ServerId3)
                    {
                        retVal=ServerId3;
                    }
                    else if (ServerId2 == ServerId3 && ServerId2 > ServerId1 && ServerId3 > ServerId1)
                    {
                        retVal=ServerId1;
                    }
                    else if (ServerId1 == ServerId3 && ServerId1 > ServerId2 && ServerId1 > ServerId3)
                    {
                        retVal=ServerId1;
                    }

        return retVal;
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

You have an `if` and a bunch of `else if` statements, but you don't have an `else` statement.  As far as the compiler is concerned, it's perfectly conceivable that none of the `if` conditions will be satisfied.  In that case, the method has no return value.

You can return a value in an `else` statement, or after the `if` construct in general.  Alternatively, if the code should indeed *never* exit the `if` statement without satisfying any of the conditions then you can throw an exception at the end of the method to indicate that there was an error.  An exception is an acceptable exit strategy for a method.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of other answers here that are addressing your specific error message, but there are more underlying issues with your method that have been overlooked.  You have a giant series of if/else if statements that are enormously long and complex just to return the minimum of 3 integers.  There are *much* easier ways of doing that.  The method with the least refactoring would be to add the following immediately after your queries:

```
return new[] { ServerId1, ServerId2, ServerId3  }.Min();
```

However, you could refactor the query itself so that you only perform one query, rather than three, and don't hard code in the three different server IDs.  This would allow you to replace everything inside of the `using` with:

```
return (from serverID in server.AppPM_Patches
where serverID.PatchStatus == "NotStarted"
group serverID  by serverID.ServerId into servers
select servers.Count())
.Min();
```

Comment: Yours is better.  Deleting mine.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have an else case so you havent covered all cases. You might have logically covered all cases but syntactically you didn't. So maybe you might want to return the first server id and just add

```
else
{
    return ServerId1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If not at least one of the `else if`s or `if` are met, then there is no "default" return.

Add a `return` at the very end, or change the last `else if` to just an `else`.

Answer (score 0):

If you reach the end of the function, you're not returning anything yet.